# Gmail Sender Android how to check sent mails

Tags: android

I am using GmailSender Android(Mail api)for sending mails,i need to know will sendmail method in GmailSender class will return any value(like boolean values)after mail sent,if mail sending failed it will throw smtp exception,but if mail is sent successfully how can i confirm that one?

Comment: I think it through exception handling

Comment: Hi,but after mail sent successfully there wont be any confirmation,which we can handle through sendmail method in mail api?

Comment: I think it is an issue, Is the mail received or not

Comment: If mail received succesfully,that can be handled in sent mail method by any confirmation?

Comment: or else if mail was not sent successfully i can get any notification other than exception?or delivery status of mails sent?

Comment: In my view, it is not possible other than exception tracking